# Cordova application icon change

Tags: android, cordova

Got an android app built on cordova 6.4.0. Want to do simple thing- change the icon from the default to my own one.
According to the doc all i need to do is to add

```
<icon src="res/logo.png" />
```

to config.xml and put my logo file to the path relative to the project's root: [PROJECT_ROOT]/res/logo.png

but when i run

```
cordova build
```

the icon does not get replaced.

I understand that the icon must be located in [PROJECT_ROOT]/platforms/android/res/mipmap-*, and i expect the CLI tool to put them there, tough it does not happen.

The tool does generate [PROJECT_ROOT]/res/mipmap-*/icon.png files from the original file, but does not copy them to [PROJECT_ROOT]/platforms/android/res/ which would be natural to expect from my perspective.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It's a bug in cordova-android 6.0.0, add 6.1.0 with cordova platform add android@latest

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your icon in `www/res` folder or you can put it in `www` folder directly, Then right path for your icon is

```
<icon src="www/res/logo.png" />
```

or

```
<icon src="www/logo.png" />
```

Because your config.xml is outside of your `www` folder so this will set your own icon to the app.

So please have a look and let me know if this is working or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
No luck still the same or even worse cause now mipmap-*  are not generated even in res directory
so far the "solution" is to copy [PROJECT_ROOT]/res/mipmap-* to  [PROJECT_ROOT]/platforms/android/res/ manually which is not very good

Comment: Have you added this in the www of root folder ?

Comment: moved from [PROJECT_ROOT]/res/logo.png to [PROJECT_ROOT]/www/res/logo.png and changed in config.xml: <icon src="www/res/logo.png" />

Comment: Yes, and it is working for me, If you are still getting the same problem then try removing and adding platform again.

Comment: Thanx, Kirankumar for the help. Most probably i got mess i this project coz i've got another cordova project and it works exactly the same as described.